# Android - Get highlight color of listview programatically (backward compatibly)

Tags: android, listview, colors

When the user presses a listview item it gets highlighted, and returns back to its original color when they let go.
I would like to programmatically query what colors these are.

On an Api version later than 14 it seems I can use
(i) Theme.resolveAttribute(int resid, TypedValue outValue, boolean resolveRefs) or 
(ii) Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(int[] attrs)

```
    //-- (i) ---------------------------------------------
    int getAttrVal(int attr)
    {
        TypedValue Val = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr, Val, true);
        return Val.data;
    }


    int colBgd = getAttrVal(android.R.attr.colorBackground);
    int colAh = getAttrVal(android.R.attr.colorActivatedHighlight);
     int colPh = getAttrVal(android.R.attr.colorPressedHighlight);  // not sure if this or prev is what im looking for!?

    // (ii) ---------------------------------------------        
     TypedArray Arr = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                      new int[] {android.R.attr.colorPressedHighlight});
      int colPh2 = arrTst.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF);
    //--------------------------------------------------
```

On older Api versions this wont work since 
android.R.attr.colorActivatedHighlight/colorPressedHighlight
were not available yet.

(1) Is there a to programmatically get these colours on api 8?
(2) I'm a bit confused as to some of the other functions in Theme

eg (iii) Theme.obtainStyledAttributes(int resid, int[] attrs)

```
    // ---------------------------------------------                     
     TypedArray Arr2 = getContext().getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
               android.R.attr.colorBackground, new int[] {android.R.attr.colorPressedHighlight});
                int colTst2 = arrTst.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF);

    Here it seems not to matter what value I use for resid. What's the point of this parameter?
```

(3) What's the difference between R.attr and R.styleable?
Is R.attr supposed to be a replacement for R.styleable (and basically have corresponding entries), or do their purposes only partly overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a selector declared with the items bellow:

```
<item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/normal" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

and set it as background for listRow

Comment: Thanks for the reply

... "set it as background"...

It sound like you misunderstood me. My question is not to set any colors, its to query what colors are being used (already)

.. "I would like to programatically query what colors these are."...
what is it exactly that your declarations achieve? Thanks in advance

Comment: oh yeah..sorry,but what for do you need to know the colors?By the way, stylable is the style for a view, attr is used to declare any attributes a view can have, and that can be modified by Style(styelable) :)

Comment: sorry but this didnt answer my question at all